# LWC multiple handlers range slider?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

Is there some easy way we could implement [lightning-slider](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-slider/example) as a multi-handler slider?

I would like to create a range input that has two or more values inside it.
As far as I searched, it seems like currently it will require a third party framework to be implemented like jquery-ui etc.. - really? seems a bit too much for this one thing...

Has anybody maybe ever implemented something like this before ?

[image: multi-handler slider]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up implementing a custom slider solution here - its not an actual lwc slider input but work close enough to it.

https://webcomponents.dev/edit/5Lc4h5DWLwKlyy3yFxAE/src/multiSlider.html